# Jquery UI sortable with NO Ajax in LARAVEL

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

I would like to change the order of my gallery pics in Laravel using Jquery UI sortable but without using the Ajax post.

I want to change the order of my gallery and when I click the normal update button, I want to pass the new order obtained to PHP using "something" between Javascript and PHP

I saw that everybody says to use jquery POST, but that works with Ajax.

Are there other ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what might work is wrapping the gallery items with a form. each gallery item should contain a hidden element with the element id and the names of the hidden element should be the same. 
e.g.

```
<form action="url_to_sort_handler" method="POST">
    <ul>
       <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="sorting_ids[]" value="id_of_item" />
            <!-- actual element here -->
       </li>
        ...
       <li>
            <input type="hidden" name="sorting_ids[]" value="id_of_item" />
            <!-- actual element here -->
       </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and then in your process script, you can loop over the sorting_ids and adjust the sorting however you want to by accessing the `$request->get('sorting_ids')` variable.

Did not test the code, just an example on how i think it could work.